# javascript filter() on http promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to filter the records object reading from http restApi endpoint based on type. If the promise is success, I am filtering the array and I display them separately in my html but looks like none of them are populating. Thanks!

```js
$http.get('/..')
        .success(..) {
            $scope.records = data;
            var temp = $scope.records.filter(function(item){
              if (item.type !== "xyzzy")
                return;
              else
                $scope.excluded.push(item);
            });
            $scope.records = temp;
        }).error(..) {
        });
```

Comment: Curly quotes are syntax errors in JS.

Comment: the callback of filter should return true or false in the test

Comment: If the callback is true or false, how to get the excluded list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#filter` will return those array elements for which the callback function returns a truthy value, but you never do that.

Change:

```
return;
```

By:

```
return true;
```

NB: You seem quite cautious by using a `temp` variable, but this really is not necessary: you can assign directly to `$scope.records`. The first assignment to `$scope.records` can also be left out if you perform the filter on `data`:

```
$scope.records = data.filter(function(item){
    if (item.type !== "xyzzy") return true;
    $scope.excluded.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Didnot realise it returns truthy value. It works